# Page speed insights is not giving results

Tags: pagespeed-insights, speed-test, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I have tested more than 10 shopify stores urls, but for every store I am getting an error.

Lighthouse returned error:

```
 NOT_HTML. The page provided is not HTML (served as MIME type text/plain)
```

I am not getting speed results.... What is the issue in the new update?

Comment: Could you list a few URLs in the comments for us that you have tested? The message itself is self explanatory as to the problem, the page is not serving content as the correct mime type, but without URLs to test against we can't offer any advice to what aspect of shopify is causing this error or which parts need the mime type setting correctly.

Comment: https://www.autumnwish.com/

Comment: https://kidora.fr/    https://wellbos.com/

Comment: https://pixibu.com/

Comment: I'm having the same problem with one of my Shopify stores https://www.tempercraft.com/